# Get UUID of specific connection?

Tags: 10.04, network-manager

Is it possible to get the UUID of a specific connection? I have used the connection before and it is set to auto when NetworkManager detects it so it is not listed in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nmcli con status` to find the UUID of the current connection or `nmcli con list` to list all configured connections.

Comment: This command does not exist in the version of nmcli shipped with Fedora 21. nmcli --version reports:
nmcli tool, version 0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21